# How to pass a parameter to another page in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

How to pass a parameter to another page in Backbone?

I used `Backbone` to `navigate` to group_edit.html, and i'd like to pass **id** to group_edit.html.

e.g

```
var routes = {};
routes[AD.page + '/edit/:_id']   = 'act_edit_group';    

act_edit_group: function(id) {  
    var t = this;            

    t.navigate("#ajax/group_edit.html", {
        trigger: true
    });
}
```

But I can't get **id** in the group_edit.html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way.

```
routes: {
    "test/:id":"home"   
  },

  home: function(id) {         
      console.log(id); 
      // "1"
  }
```

If you pass this url (localhost....#test/1 ), this route will be triggered

Hope it helps